# visualisation of categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, data-visualization

Can anyone help me how to plot/visualise 2-3 categorical variables all togehter at the same time. I have 4 different categorical variables each with 4 levels. I want to visualise the first 3 variables (each separtely) against the fourth variable. Please help me I can share the data if it is helpful. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a mosaic plot matrix.

Mosaic plots are a good way of showing the relationship in pairs of categorical variables. A mosaic plot matrix is a collection of such plots.  If you have R, you can create these plots using the mosaicpairs function in the vcd library.

Comment: @ Peter, Thank you for your suggestions. I am trying to find the source coding or similar example to run the Mosaic plot matrix, but it's really difficult. I have 5 categorical variables such as 1: region (3 levels), 2: bamboo use (4 levels), 3: timber (4 levels), 4: vegetables (4 levels) etc. I would like to plot each of the uses (# 2,3,4 variables) against the region variable in the same mosaic matrix. so region variable is the predictor variable. Can you please provide me any example/tutorial for this. thank you again.

Comment: I don't know of any, offhand. There may be a vignette or something.

Comment: `R`'s base graphics include `mosaicplot`.